# how to vent an electric dryer when outdoors isn't option

Tags: venting

We have a building on the 3rd floor of a 4 floor building that we are building a loft in,  It is in an historic area, we are in the middle of the block downtown.  size 21'wide x 180'long, left and right walls are 18" of brick with plaster overlay. venting through the roof isn't an option.  do they make a ul rated dryer lint box or can a vented electric dryer be vented to a converter of sorts to stay in code for indoors.  I am at a cross roads I have a brand new electric washer and dryer I bought a year ago.  I cannot take it back and I am trying to find a way to complete this project so the building inspector will let us move in.  Do you have any info or options.  Thanks so much

Comment: Do you have a water and electric hook up for these??

Answer (score 5):

The proper answer for this, and certainly the one the building was built for, is to use a **condensing dryer**. This is a special dryer with a dehumidifier built in, which then overboards the recovered moisture into the drain  intended for the washer.

I suppose you could do the same thing with an actual dehumdifier.  If you can find a way to install it above the washer drain, almost any model will let you  route a hose from its output,  so the bucket never fills up.   Some dehumidifiers also have a water pump to push the drain water uphill if needed.

Comment: You can even get condensing dryers which capture the water and thus don’t need drain access.

Answer (score 2):

Although 18" of brick would be difficult to drill thru, it can be done. Check your local listings for a company which cuts/drills concrete. I have had a local company drill thru 12" of concrete block with 6" of natural stone veneer. With the proper bits and drills, it should be doable for a pro; however, it will NOT be cheap. My 4" hole cost me $300, but it was money well spent. Trying to chisel and break thru would have been near impossible and would have looked terrible. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lint trap/condensing box if you want to.

[Dryer lint trap picture](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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)

It is messy, and doesn't work particularly well, and you'll wind up heating up your apartment in the summer, but it does work.

I used one for 8+ years.

Condensing dryers work much better.

Answer (score 1):

#### Window

My dryer originally vented indoors, which was OK (except for the lint) in winter and horrible in the summer. I moved the dryer in order to be able to vent it out through a window. I cut a piece of plywood to replace a section of the window and cut a hole in that for the vent.

Obviously if there is no window in that room then it gets a little harder to do this, but according to [this web site on dryer vent safety](https://www.nachi.org/dryer-vent-safety.htm), you can potentially go as far as 35 feet.